# How to launch Firefox Browser minimized with a .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, imacros

I want this batch file to execute both windows of Mozilla Firefox minimized (The one that opens http://google.com and the one that runs the iMacro google.iim)
Thanks

```
    :loop 
    cls
    taskkill /F /IM Firefox.exe
    cls
    taskkill /F /IM crashreporter.exe
    cls
    TIMEOUT /T 5
    start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-remote -private-window http://google.com imacros://run/?m=google.iim
    TIMEOUT /T 555
    GOTO loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your command starts a the firefox with a title that starts with `imacros ...`.
You can try to use [`sendkeys.bat`](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat) :

```
:loop 
cls
taskkill /F /IM Firefox.exe
cls
taskkill /F /IM crashreporter.exe
cls
TIMEOUT /T 5
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-remote -private-window http://google.com imacros://run/?m=google.iim
TIMEOUT /T 5
call sendkeys.bat "imacros" "% "
call sendkeys.bat "imacros" "n"
TIMEOUT /T 555
GOTO loop
```